# Not able to query documents by geohash in google firestore, using created date field?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, geofire, geofirestore

I am using Google Firestore geoqueries [Following this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries). Querying documents within a distance using geohash works fine. When I introduce a new condition: `.whereField("createdOn", isGreaterThan: <**value for time interval since 1970 7 days ago**>)

This throws an error saying, any inequality on a field must have this field as the first 'OrderBy' parameter. When I add order by parameter for this field, it no longer returns the document that is still within the distance searched but shows no error.

Is it even possible to use the firestore geoqueries with additional query conditions?

I need to be able to limit the query by objects created within a certain timeframe, otherwise this will return a very large number of documents. Sorting these post-query will surely impact app performance. Maybe I am missing a more practical way of using geoqueries in Firestore?

```
 let queryBounds = GFUtils.queryBounds(forLocation: center,
                                              withRadius: distanceM)
    
    //test
    let ref = Ref().databaseJobs
    let currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let intervalLastWeek = currentTime - (10080 * 60)
    print("current time is: \(currentTime) and 7 days ago interval was \(intervalLastWeek)")
    ref.whereField("createdOn", isGreaterThan: intervalLastWeek)
    
    
    let queries = queryBounds.compactMap { (any) -> Query? in
        guard let bound = any as? GFGeoQueryBounds else { return nil }
        return ref
            .order(by: "geohash")
            .start(at: [bound.startValue])
            .end(at: [bound.endValue])
            .whereField("createdOn", isGreaterThan: intervalLastWeek)
```

Comment: The geohash method is a rather basic way to geoquery–maybe even primitive or bordering on obsolete. Unfortunately with Firestore (and other cloud NoSQL), you have only one range operation to use per query so you'll have to choose between geohashes or dates. That said, you can explore more robust geoquerying libraries like H3 by Uber, which can be configured to geoquery without the use of range operations. There are also service providers like Algolia that can give you geoquerying functionality, but they may be more expensive than simply overquerying and filtering client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can only filter on range on a single field. Or simpler: you can only have a single `orderBy` clause in your query.

What you are trying to do requires two `orderBy` clauses, one for `geohash` and one for `createdOn`, which isn't possible. If you were to need an equality check on a second field though, that would be possible as thstt doesn't require an `orderBy` clause.

What I'm wondering is whether you can add a field `createdOnDay` that contains just the day part of `createdOn` in a fixed format, and then perform an `in` on that with 7 values (for the days of the past week?

Comment: Yes, I could for the past week actually this would work. But I need to be able to scale the ranges further back. So right now I have items posted (created) in (1) Past week (2) Past Month (3) Past 3 Months (4) All. I have watched your Querying Firebase/Firestore presentation before which was very interesting and actually what led me down this route. I know you're involved, so wondering do you know if the near roadmap will enhance geoqueries to support this? Since I'm building the production app with Firestore as the backend, would be useful to know so I can explore options.